# How to show data in Vue tab in devtools?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.7

I have a categories table with below picture.

[image: Categories]

When I click `Cars` I want to display message in Vue devtools. While I do not want to display arrays.

[image: Array]

I want to show this

[image: Vuejs]

What do I want to show?

Advert.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li v-for="category in categories" @click="sendAdvert(category.id)" class="list-group-item display">{{ category.name }}</li>
        </ul>
        <!--<ul class="list-group">-->
            <!--<li class="list-group-item hide">{{ category.name }}</li>-->
        <!--</ul>-->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['categories'],
        data() {
            return {
                adverts: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            sendAdvert: function (id) {
                const self = this;

                axios.post('adverts/', {
                    id: id
                }).then(response => {
                    this.adverts = response.data;
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('adverts', 'AdvertController');
```

AdvertController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('Home.adverts', ['categories' => $categories]);
    //$categories = Category::where('parent_id', 0)->get();
    //return view('Home.adverts', compact('categories'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $category = Category::find($id);
    return $category;
}
```

Comment: you want to display the data to your `view` or to your `dev tools`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **AdvertController.php** controller `store()` method should be responsible to add new record.

You should be using `show()` method instead.

You can read more about `Route::resource()` in [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers)

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    return Category::find($id);
}
```

And in your **Advert.vue**, `methods` should look like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li
              v-for="category in categories"
              @click="sendAdvert(category.id)"
              class="list-group-item display"
            >
              {{ category.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['categories'],
        data() {
            return {
                advert:         [],
            }
        },

        methods: {
            sendAdvert(id) {
                // this will load single advert
                axios.get('/adverts/'+id)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.advert = response.data;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.  but I have a problem. When I clicked on `Cars`, it hides all.
I don't for now want to hide any of they.

Comment: I've updated my answer, and removed `showCategories` variable. This will remove hiding

Comment: When I click on Cars. The result is nothing. [Vue.js][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/94qrd.png

Comment: Check your browser devtools, network panel. You can double click on the request and open it in new tab (if it's GET request). Is the ajax request being sent? Does the route return the category for the given id.

Comment: I see this I see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FUXK.png in network tab.

Comment: Check the response sub-panel. Also, you can open the link http://localhost:8000/adverts/4 to see what's returned. Ajax is being sent, now you need to debug your logic in the controller

Comment: I see nothing but `[]` on the page

Comment: Now you need to debug just the backend. Open the http://localhost:8000/adverts/4 and then try to figure out why the response is `[]`. Check the logic in controller, check the values in database - does the record with id `4` exist?

Comment: Yes, the record with id 4 exist. I have 10 id records.

Comment: I changed `$id` to `$advert` in `show` function.  I see this message  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJA92.png ! And I have a problem when I click on Cars it does not open list.

Comment: It's hard to help when I'm not sure if all the code in this question is what you currently have. It's better to create new question with the new code that you have, and provide the link here.

Comment: check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271912/how-to-show-data-in-database-in-vue-devtools and answer my question