# How to show data in database in Vue devtools?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.7

When I click in `Cars`. I want show me the image below.

Has anyone experienced this problem? I'm using Vue Devtools but can't inspect any components on a count of none are showing up.

[image: Devtools]

**Advert.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li v-for="category in categories" @click="sendAdvert(category.id)" class="list-group-item display">
                {{ category.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['categories'],
        data() {
            return {
                advert: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sendAdvert(id) {
                axios.get('/adverts/'+id)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.advert = response.data;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

AdvertController.php

```
public function show(Request $request, $advert)
{
    return Category::find($advert);
}
```

Comment: Any warning or error in the console?

Comment: Can you show your **App.vue**? And how you create `new Vue({...` instance

Comment: Yes I added in my blade.php, But now I want to show in vue-devtools.